# GivenStories is not working in JBehave

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I need to include some preconditions in my Main story. I have used the Givenstories: in my Main story to achieve it. But i has no effect. My main story start running with out calling the precondition story.

My stories are,

Main story:

```
GivenStories: preconditions/Login.story

Scenario: some scenario
Given some step
When some another step
Then some check
```

Login Story:

```
Scenario: Loginscenario
Given some step
When some another step
Then some check
```

In console, It prints just as
     GivenStories: preconditions/Login.story

I have tried to arrange the Main story as below.

Main story after edit:

```
Scenario: some scenario
GivenStories: preconditions/Login.story
Given some step
When some another step
Then some check
```

Now i can able to run it, but Please let me know where i am going wrong in the first method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your step factory of the parent story (Main story) to include steps for the `Login.story` as well.

Comment: They are already. i assume it doesn't even invoke the precondition story.because it is not printing the Scenario texts of the precondition story.

Comment: @Karthikeyan In which folder are the stories located?

Comment: Both stories are residing in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after several failed attempts I tried :
GivenStories: preconditions\Login.story   (change the slash to backslash)

This worked. When I changed it back to forward slash, it still worked.